# script is overwriting the current data in the googlesheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using **GoogleSheets**.  I have a smiple script to insert text in a cell.

```
function anotherTest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest Results:');
};
```

I assigned the script to a button.  In the googlesheets, I click on the cell that I want the text to appear and then I click on the button.  The text is inserted into the cell.

The problem is that when my script runs, anything that is in that cell is overwriten.  I don't want the text to be overwritten.  How can I prevent text from being overwrtiten  when my script runs?  In addition, how can I point to a position in the cell and have the text inserted into that position when the script runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `setValue()` means that you set the content of a cell to the value you specify, no matter what the previous content of this cell was

There is no way to point to a certain position, but if you want to add text in addition to the already existing one instead of overwriting, you can modify your script as following:

```
function anotherTest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var oldContent = cell.getValue();
  var newContent = 'Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest Results:';
  var space = " ";
  cell.setValue(oldContent + space + newContent);
};
```

Obviously you can play around with the order, e.g.
`cell.setValue(newContent + space + oldContent);` is also possible